# LISP Do function behaviour?

Tags: lisp

I have this list code block.

```
(defun test (y)
    (do 
        ((l NIL (setq y (rest y))))
        ((null y) 1)
        (setq l (append l '(1 1)))
        (print l)
    )
)
```

And the output is pictured below. For some reason it's setting l to y and then appending '(1 1). Can anyone explain this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of a `do` loop is:

```
(do ((var init-form step-form))
    (termination-form result-form)
  (body))
```

I think what you're missing is that `step-form` is  executed at every iteration and the *result* of this form is set to the variable.  So using `setq` in the `step-form` is a flag that you're probably not doing what you intend.

So the sequence of the loop from `(test '(2 3 4))` is (eliding the print)

```
 - Initialize l to nil
 - Check (null y) which is false since y = '(2 3 4).
 - (setq l (append l '(1 1))) l now has the value '(1 1)
 - Execute the step form, this sets y = '(3 4) _and_ l = '(3 4)
 - (null y) still false.
 -  (setq l (append l '(1 1))) sets l = '(3 4 1 1)
 - Execute step form, sets y = '(4) _and_ l = '(4)
 - (setq l (append l '(1 1))) sets l = '(4 1 1)
 - Execute step form, y = () so loop terminates.
```

Comment: Ah thanks for explaining it so well! Definitely cleared up my confusions.